# Raster Stack with Sentinel-2 data

Tags: r, sentinel-2, rasterstack

I need to do a rasterstack of Sentinel-2 data in R. I've done it before with Landsat data by using the library RStoolbox, raster and rgdal. These are the script lines:

```
meta2009<-readMeta(C:/.../MTL.txt)
```

How can I do the same for Sentinel-2 knowing that it doesn't have MTL.txt metadata?

Comment: Add the "r" tag to any of your R-related questions!

Answer (score 1):

You can do a rasterstack without that file, by simply using the default raster method.

```
setwd(your_directory)

# open library
library(raster)

# open bands
r<-raster('T30TUK_20180427T110621_B04.jp2')
g<-raster('T30TUK_20180427T110621_B03.jp2')
b<-raster('T30TUK_20180427T110621_B02.jp2')

# stack your bands
rgb<-stack(r,g,b)

# visualize result
plotRGB(rgb, stretch='lin')
```

Comment: You do not need to read in the individual bands as objects, simply pass the on disk rasters to `raster::stack` as a vector ie., `rgb <- raster::stack(c('T30TUK_20180427T110621_B04.jp2', 'T30TUK_20180427T110621_B03.jp2', 'T30TUK_20180427T110621_B02.jp2'))`  You can do the same in terra with the `terra::rast` function, which now handles single or multi band as a single object class.